# difficulty configuring rails console to identify an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newish to rails and programming and having a spot of bother in the rails console configuring such to identify myself as a administrator. Immediately after the user.save command is executed my admin value still remains false and I get a console note that says.

> Console

```
0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false
```

Here is what I have done so far.

> _add_admin_to_users.rb

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

> Rails console admin save process

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'your-eamiladdress@example.tld')
user.admin = true
user.save
user.admin?
```

> user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


    has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy   

    validates :name, presence: true  

 def admin?
     admin
 end

end
```

Comment: do this instead `user.save! `, it will show you the error for which the `save` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some validation or something fails in save so all process cancelled, you can see there are text like this:

```
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false 

 It means save process rollback

 Use user.save! to see error and it seems to me error due to validation on name field of user
```

Try this:

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'your-eamiladdress@example.tld')
user.name = "Admin"
user.admin = true
user.save
user.admin?
```

Comment: When I input your command of user.save! it returns an error that says ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank

Comment: how can I resolve this and what is this pertaining to

Comment: Before saving user,  set name of the user for admin you can set like: 
user = User.find_by(email: 'your-eamiladdress@example.tld')....   user.name = "Admin"

then rest of your code

Comment: I mean you have to assign a name to user before save it

Comment: what is the syntax for that

Comment: Sir i really appreciate your help, that worked beautifully

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by escaping validation

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'your-eamiladdress@example.tld')
user.admin = true
```

Now before rails < 3

```
user.save(false)
user.admin?
```

Or after rails 3

```
user.save(:validate => false)
user.admin?
```

or if you do not want to escape validation

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'your-eamiladdress@example.tld')
user.name = "Admin"
user.admin = true
user.save
user.admin?
```